# spark streaming to neo4j

Tags: neo4j, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to input Spark Streaming output to Neo4j as a graph in real time. Is there any way to do that. If so, can you share some example code?. I have seen Mazerunner, but it only inputs graph data from Neo4j to Spark-Graphx. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Mazerunner also writes data back.

Easiest would be to use a Neo4j connector to Neo4j server and write data back concurrently. Neo4j 2.2+ can sustain (quite) high concurrent write load.

For scala you can use [AnormCypher](http://www.anormcypher.org) and for Python [py2neo](http://py2neo.org)

I'm currently looking into spark integration for Neo4j, so it would help a lot if you could detail your use-case a bit. E.g. do you use plain Spark (RDD / DStream) or GraphX?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The use case is - I want to built a co-occurrence graph(In a tweet -words will become nodes and the if the words are from same tweet we add an edge between them) from the streaming twitter data using spark streaming. Once we do our transformations I need to push that into Neo4j. I am using DStreams as i am using spark streaming.

Comment: what do you mean by mazerunner also writes data back - Is it that mazerunner writes graphx output to respective Neo4j nodes.

Comment: I need a way to connect spark streaming to neo4j. I can't understand how "Easiest would be to use a Neo4j connector to Neo4j server and write data back concurrently. Neo4j 2.2+ can sustain (quite) high concurrent write load." helps my use case

Comment: Why not? I mean you can just use a library that connects and writes to Neo4j from Spark (I mentioned two).

Comment: Thank you. Can you share any examples on how to get data from spark streaming to Neo4j by using py2neo?